# KeyError after renaming the first n column names of python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

We have a simple input file as in the picture. We load the csv input into pandas dataframe, and we want to rename the first n-th columns, in this example, the first three columns.

[image]

The code

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = r"C:\Codes\test\test_data.csv"
df1 = pd.read_csv(file_path)
print (df1, "\n", type(df1), "\n", df1.columns, "\n", type(df1.columns), "\n", df1.columns.values, "\n", type(df1.columns.values))

df2 = df1.copy()
print (df2, "\n", type(df2), "\n", df2.columns, "\n", type(df2.columns), "\n", df2.columns.values, "\n", type(df2.columns.values))

df2.columns.values[0:3] = ["symbol","field","abc"]  
print("\n after renaming the columns: ", df2)
print(df2["symbol"])
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

It seems that the code `df2.columns.values[0:3] = ["symbol","field","abc"]`  is not stable. Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not, for example, it may report an "KeyError" or the code freeze when trying to display `df2`. I do understand why it does not work.
I am working on Windows 10, with Python 3.10.4

Of course, I can also write the following code, which works

```
df2.rename(columns={df2.columns[0]:  "symbol"},inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={df2.columns[1]:  "field"},inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={df2.columns[2]:  "abc"},inplace=True)
```

But my goal is to change the first n-th columns in a simple code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try updating the column labels like this:

```py
df2 = df2.rename(columns=dict(zip(list(df2.columns)[0:3], ["symbol","field","abc"])))
```

... or like this:

```
df2.columns = ["symbol","field","abc"] + list(df2.columns)[3:]
```

Output:

```
   COLA  COL_B  testC
0     1      2      3
1    10     11     12
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 Index(['COLA', 'COL_B', 'testC'], dtype='object')
 <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
 ['COLA' 'COL_B' 'testC']
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
   COLA  COL_B  testC
0     1      2      3
1    10     11     12
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 Index(['COLA', 'COL_B', 'testC'], dtype='object')
 <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
 ['COLA' 'COL_B' 'testC']
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

 after renaming the columns:
   symbol  field  abc
0       1      2    3
1      10     11   12
df2["symbol"]
0     1
1    10
Name: symbol, dtype: int64
```

Note that the docs for [`Index.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.values.html#pandas.Index.values) have a warning which reads:

> We recommend using Index.array or Index.to_numpy(), depending on whether you need a reference to the underlying data or a NumPy array.

Comment: thanks, do you know why `df2.columns.values[0:3] = ["symbol","field","abc"]` is not stable? This code works on my pc well for some days and suddenly one day it does not work anymore, and the error message is not stable, i.e. sometimes it is KeyError and sometimes it just freeze.

Comment: I'm not certain why you're seeing unstable behavior for `Index.values` in your environment. I know the docs recommend using [`Index.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_numpy.html#pandas.Index.to_numpy) instead of `Index.values`, but converting `columns` to a list seems easier since we want to manipulate it and combine it with a list of new column labels.